# Scrapy not always finding the object

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a hidden field on a webpage, with python's scrapy framework:

```
<input class="currentTime" value="4888599" />
```

The strange thing is, on about 40% of all pages it cannot find the value of the input field. I tried loading the failing pages with javaScript disabled (thought maybe that's the problem) inside my browser, but the value is just filled on the pages which are failing. So the value is not added with javaScript....

Anyone who had this problem before or might have a solution for this? I don't know why it cannot find the value. I'm using the following syntax to scrape:

```
sel.css('.currentTime::attr(value)').extract()
```

The class is just available once on a page and I'm searching from the body tag. So it cannot be the path which is wrong, to my opinion. It's only that object which cannot be found most of the time, all other objects are not a problem.

Comment: Have you tried using `scrapy shell` and checking the `response.body`?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Seems like the website returns a different page when I try to scrape it.... The ```response.body``` does not contain an input field with the currentTime class.

Comment: Do you have a link we can try, to find a solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the CSS attributes, you should prefer XPath - it's much more powerful and allows you to do things like traverse the tree backwards (for parents, which you can then descend down again)

Not that you'd need to do this in the given example, but XPath is much more reliable in general.

A fairly generic xpath query to do what you want would be something like this.. (in the case where the node may have more than one class name

```
//input[contains(concat(' ',normalize-space(@class),' '),' currentTime ')]/value/text()
```

A more targeted example would be..

```
//input[@class="currentTime"]/value/text()
```